# Asana Workspace is_organization Value

Tags: asana

The [Asana API documentation](http://developer.asana.com/documentation/#workspaces) states that when querying all workspaces with `https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/workspaces` that it will return an `is_organization` value (set to `true` or `false`) depending on the kind of workspace the user has.

When I GET `/workspaces` I do not see this value come down with the workspace payload. Only the workspace `id` and `name` are available.

Will `is_organization` only appear if it's `true` and it's omitted entirely if its value is `false`?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the fields to return with the `?opt_fields` option. For your request, this would be something like `https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/workspaces?opt_fields=name,is_organization`.

Note that the results may not be what you expect. I was surprised to see that even my Personal Projects workspace returned true for `is_organization`.